# Is there a way to do this synchronously?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim requestUri As String = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/GetBalance"
    Dim postData = New With { _
        Key .Currency = "DOT" _
    }

    ' Create Request
    Dim request = New HttpRequestMessage()
    request.Method = HttpMethod.Post
    request.RequestUri = New Uri(requestUri)
    request.Content = New ObjectContent(GetType(Object), postData, New JsonMediaTypeFormatter()) 'I still don't get what the hell is this
    Dim sometring6 = Await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() '"{"Currency":"DOT"}"
```

So basically there is this anonymous type. I want a json string version of it.

It seems that putting it in request.Content and then read that asynchronously seems very strange.

It makes program much harder to debug.

What would be the simpler way?

Comment: The types you're using are intended to be used asynchronously. If you don't want to use asynchrony then don't use those types.  That said, why exactly is it an issue?

Comment: All you're accomplishing here is producing JSON from an anonymous type instance. Couldn't you just import the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package and do `Dim somestring6 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData)`?

Comment: Okay. I will try that.

Comment: Any way to do so without outside library?